# Is there a linear transformation that sends $v$ to $(1,0)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose we are given a linear vector field $v(x) = Ax$ on $\Bbb R^2$. Suppose $x_0$ is the point where this vector field does not vanish. Is it possible to find a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$ that, when restricted to a neighborhood of $x_0$, sends $v$ to $(1, 0)$?

Comment: What is $v$ in "sends $v$ to $(1,0)$"?

Comment: Sorry i meant $V$ (neighbourhood of $x_0$).

Comment: So the map should send the entire neighborhood $V$ to the vector $(1,0)$?

Comment: I don't understand your question exactly. It might be useful that whenever you have the basis $(b_i)i$ and $(a_i)i$ of $\mathbb{k}^{n}$, then the map $f(a_i)=b_i$ can be extended to an k-linear-isomorphism of  $\mathbb{k}^{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking if it is possible to find a transformation which you can use so that the vector field has image $(1,0)$ at a particular point.

The answer is yes. Describe $v(x)$ in polar coordinates. Rotate the vector field around so that it is parallel to the $x-$axis. Then rescale the vector field so that it has image exactly $(1,0)$. Since both rotation and rescaling are linear maps, the composition is a linear map, and and in particular is an isomorphism.